# C Language : Error in implementing binary search tree using structures

Tags: c, file, struct, binary-search-tree, function-pointers

```
/* These are struct definitions I am using */
struct PdsNdxInfo{
    int key;
    int offset;
};

struct PdsInfo{
    FILE *repo_fptr;
    FILE *ndx_fptr;
    char repo_name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    int repo_status;  
    int num_recs;
    struct PdsNdxInfo ndxEntries[MAX_RECS];
};


/*This is the code */

//BST Creation
struct PdsNdxInfo temp[pdsInfo.num_recs];
fseek(pdsInfo.ndx_fptr,0,SEEK_SET);
fread(temp, sizeof(struct  PdsNdxInfo), pdsInfo.num_recs, pdsInfo.ndx_fptr);


int i=0;
while(i < pdsInfo.num_recs){
    printf("********%d  %d",temp[i].key,temp[i].offset);
    if(root==NULL) {
        root =insert(root,temp[i].key,temp[i].offset); //getting error
    }
    else {
        insert(root,temp[i].key,temp[i].offset);
    }
    i++;    
}

/* This is the function definition */
struct node *newNode(int k,int o){
    struct node *temp =  (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->key = k;temp->offset = o;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

struct node* insert(struct node* root, int k,int o) {
    if (root == NULL) return newNode(k,o);
    if (k < root->key)
    root->left  = insert(root->left, k,o);
    else if (k > root->key)
    root->right = insert(root->right, k,o);   

    return root;
}
```

Compiler error:

```
pds_version2.c: In function ‘pds_store’:
pds_version2.c:119:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer 
without a cast [enabled by default]
root = insert(root,pdsInfo.ndxEntries[pdsInfo.num_recs-
1].key,pdsInfo.ndxEntries[pdsInfo.num_recs-1].offset);
     ^
pds_version2.c: At top level:
pds_version2.c:180:14: error: conflicting types for ‘insert’
struct node* insert(struct node* root, int k,int o)
          ^
pds_version2.c:66:10: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘insert’ 
was here
root =insert(root,temp[i].key,temp[i].offset);
```

Not able to figure out why the error is happening basically I am trying to create Binary search tree and above are the two methods insert and newnode but getting compile time errors.

New node is a struct with two pointers left and right and two data values. But I am not able to figure out why such error "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]" is occuring

Comment: Please, indent your code and add to the question the part of *"BST Creation"* left. At least how it starts and the declaration of `root`.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  When you create an MCVE, you can post the compiler errors for the exact code you show, with the exact matching line numbers.  Granted, modern GCC includes the information about the lines it is complaining about in the error message (it was not always thus, and in those days, it was a lot more crucial to have the code in the question match the line numbers in the compiler messages), so you can more nearly get away with a mish-mash.  But you should still show code that can be submitted to the compiler to get the same error as you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the insert function before where you use it.
Or simply put the function declaration before:

```
struct node* insert(struct node* root, int k,int o);

void code()
{
  //use insert function here
}
struct node* insert(struct node* root, int k,int o)
{
  //insert function definition
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Rossi88 . Thank you so much again (y) !!